# Why won't my Vaillant thermostat's remote control pair with the base unit?

Tags: thermostat, boiler, uk

A couple of months ago I installed a brand new Vaillant room thermostat ([VRT 350f](https://www.vaillant.co.uk/for-installers/products/vrt-350-350f-4160.html)) for my quite old Vaillant boiler (ecoTEC plus 937). It was a breeze to install and did its job perfectly until yesterday when I noticed the remote control had **lost its RF connection with the receiver**.  I followed the same process as when I commissioned the controller in order to pair the unit again. **It won't pair**.

According to the manual, when you press the "Teach-in" button on the receiver *"the green LED will start flashing"* (it doesn't) during which time the controller has 15 minutes to find it (it doesn't). I've tried this after a factory reset on the controller too, but the fact **the receiver LED doesn't illuminate** at any point leads me to think the controller is not the problem. This light should come on whether there's a controller there or not.

**The boiler itself is running fine** in terms of heating and hot water.

Before I declare the receiver unit is faulty, are there any possible faults with the boiler that could be relevant? Is there a way to verify that the eBUS itself is actually working? I can't find much useful information about Vaillant eBUS as it's proprietary. But can I check for voltage or something between the terminals? Is there some diagnostic menu function on the boiler I can run?

The radio receiver is installed apart from the boiler via a line from the receiver unit's PCB into the eBUS. As opposed to being installed on the boiler's front panel.

---

**Update**

I tried installing the receiver unit on the front panel of the boiler, and it works fine. I get shorter RF range due to the location of the boiler, so not ideal. I'd still like to know if the issue is with the eBUS terminals inside the boiler or their connections on the receiver unit when wired externally.

Comment: This seems to be a pretty esoteric question, very product-specific. What does the Vaillant tech support department say about this problem?

Comment: It is an esoteric question, but I hoped someone might know how to test the eBUS terminals in order to blame the fault on either the unit or the boiler. Possibly this should be the title of my post instead

Comment: You don't get support if you're a DIYer. Or a warrantee on the 150 quid unit for that matter.